# You are a stupid vs you are stupid

Tags: sentence-meaning, articles

1. You are a stupid.
2. You are a stupid person.
3. You are stupid.

Which one is correct? is there any different meaning?

Answer (score 2):

"Stupid" is an adjective. In general, an adjective cannot be used as a noun in English. An adjective must be attached to a noun or, via a linking verb, to a pronoun.

> He is stupid.

The adjective "stupid" is attached to the pronoun "he" via the linking verb "is." That is perfectly good grammar and concise style as well.

> He is a stupid person

The adjective "stupid" is attached directly to the noun "person," and the entire noun phrase "stupid person" is linked to the pronoun "he" via the verb "is." That is perfectly good grammar.

The two sentences mean the same thing, and both are idiomatic.

> He is a stupid

is not grammatical in English though similar constructions are acceptable in some other languages. The sentence would be understood, but it is the kind of thing a toddler of three years might say. It is not the speech of a native born adult.

Comment: Oxford dictioneries say it(stupid) can be used as a noun in informal English.If that would be so why not He is a stupid is currect???

Comment: Would you care to give the citation? I did not find any such statement in the online oxford. What I did find was "stupid" used informally as a term of address.  You will appear to be stupid if you say "He is a stupid." For the sake of your own reputation as a speaker of English, avoid using adjectives as nouns.

Comment: We had people of a certain genius who would go on to great things; and we had our fair share of stupids. It's a sentence  in the oxford-dictionariey. Here stupids os the object of preposition OF, isn't it? How do you explain it? Thank you, @ Jeff Morrow.